# Javascript nested loops to output rectangle with text

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm needing help with loops. Yes this is for an assignment. So I need more help with understanding the logic and output.

I need to do the first rectangle in a nested for loop, the second with nested while loop, and last with nested do while loop.

This is my code so far.

```js
function myFunctions() {
  //setting columns and rows to zero for user input
  var columns = 0;
  var rows = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) //I believe this is right logically
  {
    rows = ; //don't know what to put logic wise here.
    // if I can get the logic of the first one I should be able to get the others.
    document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML = text;

    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++;) {
      columns = ; //or here
      document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML = text;
    }
  }
}

function myFunctions() {
  var columns = 0;
  var rows = 0;
  while (…) {
    while (…) {

    }
  }
  document.getElementById("whileloop").innerHTML = text;
}

function myFunctions() {
  var columns = 0;
  var rows = 0;
  do {
    do {

    } while (…)

  } while (…)
  document.getElementById("dowhileloop").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>My Kung Fu Panda <br/>Po Magic Rectangle</br>
  </h1>
  <!--Making a header-->
</header>

<section>
  <p><b>Enter's Po's row and column numbers.</b></p>

  <!--I believe the input types are correct but I need Css to fix the look of them?-->
  <form>
    Po's row: <input type="text" size="30" input="rows">
  </form>

  <form>
    Po's column: <input type="text" size="24" input="columns">
  </form>
  <br>

  <button onclick="myFunctions()">Generate Po's magic rectangle.</button>
  <br>
  <!--This button will help count down using a for loop-->

  <p><b>Po's magic rectangle: </b></p>
</section>

<p id="forloop"></p>
<p id="whileloop"></p>
<p id="dowhileloop"></p>
```

As you can see I'm having a lot of trouble. I also have a CSS file linked to this.

This is what my output should look like for once user input is entered.

For example: (the 3 and the 5 are user input so it's subject to whatever is entered.)

```
Po's Magic Rectangle:
Po's magic rectangle has 3 rows, 5 columns.

Nested for loop rectangle
FFFFF
FFFFF
FFFFF

Nested while loop rectangle
W,row1,col1; W,row1,col2; W,row1,col3; W,row1,col4; W,row1,col5;
W,row2,col1; W,row2,col2; W,row2,col3; W,row2,col4; W,row2,col5;
W,row3,col1; W,row3,col2; W,row3,col3; W,row3,col4; W,row3,col5;

Nested do...while loop rectangle
1x1=1; 1x2=2; 1x3=3; 1x4=4, 1x5=5;
2x1=2; 2x2=4; 2x3=6; 2x4=8; 2x5=10;
3x1=3; 3x2=6; 3x3=9; 3x4=12; 3x5=15;
```

So I've played with my code a little since yesterday and this is what I have now. It doesn't do what I need it to do and I stuck with "F" for the output on the rectangles until I understand how to even get this to generate output.

Any help would be much appreciated :) Thank you for everyone's help so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Author: Me-->

<html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <!--Linking my external stylesheet-->

        <title>My Kung Fu Panda Po Magic Rectangle</title> 
        </head>

        <section>
        <header>
        <h1>My Kung Fu Panda <br>Po Magic Rectangle</h1>
        </header>

        <p><b>Enter Po's Row and Column Numbers: </b></p>
        <form name="input" onsubmit="return false;">
        <label for="rows">Po's Row: </label>
        <input type="text"  name="rows" id="rows"><br>
        <label for="columns">Po's Column: </label>
        <input type="text"  name="columns" id="columns"><br>
        <br><button onclick="MagicRectangle();">Generate Po's Magic Rectangle</button>
        </form>
        </section>

        <p><b>Po's magic rectangle: </b></p>
        </section>

        <script type="text/JavaScript"> <!--Using javascript-->
            function MagicRectangle()
            {
            //setting columns and rows to zero for user input
            var Column = 0;
            var Row = 0;
            var outputText = " ";

                for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++;) 
                {
                    outputText = outputText + "F";

                    for (var j = 0; j < Column; j++;) 
                    { 
                        outputText = outputText + "<br>";
                    }
                } 
                Row = document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML = outputText;
                Column = document.getElementById("columns").innerHTML = outputText;
            }

            function MagicRectangle()
            {   
            var Column = 0;
            var Row = 0;
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            var outputText = " ";

                while (Row > 0 )
                {
                    outputText = outputText + "F";
                    i++;

                    while (Column > 0) 
                    { 
                        outputText = outputText + "<br>";
                        j++;
                    }
                } 
                Row = document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML = outputText;
                Column = document.getElementById("columns").innerHTML = outputText;     
                }

            function MagicRectangle()
            {
            var Column = 0;
            var Row = 0;
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            var outputText = " ";

                do
                {
                    outputText = outputText + "F";
                    i++;
                    do {

                    outputText = outputText + "<br>";
                    j++;
                        }while (Row > 0)

                } while (Column > 0) 

                Row = document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML = outputText;
                Column = document.getElementById("columns").innerHTML = outputText;
            }
        </script>


        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should break down the problem into steps and tackle them one at a time.
Once you understand what's happening in this FOR loop you'll be able to apply the logic to the other loops extending where needed.

```
function myForLoopFunction()
{
    // assuming you'll implement user input later, let's just give them a value for now
    var columns = 5; // as per your sample
    var rows = 3;
    var outputText = '' // we'll use this to store our output
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++;)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++;) 
        { 
            outputText = outputText + "F"
        }
        outputText = outputText + "<br>"
    } 
    document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML = outputText // just set this once
}
```

Comment: Okay :) that's very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so I got the basic logic down on all of them now I think. I'm having trouble with connecting the user input from the <input type ="text" > html to the functions though.

Comment: @Saiba the easiest method would be to set the id="rowInput" inside <input> tag and then you can access the value by doing rows = document.getElementById('rowInput').value

Comment: @Saiba and remember you can test values by doing alert(rows); after setting it

Comment: Oh, okay. I completely forgot about the id tag for some reason. Thank you again :)